# как указать что минусовое значения числа тоже чило?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = input()

if not x.isdigit() : print("123"); exit()
x=int(x)

if x< -5: print("low") ;exit()
elif -5<= x <=5 :print("mid")
else : print("high")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
  x=int(x)
except ValueError:
  exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, например, можно так:

```
if not x.isdigit() and not (x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit()):
```

Хотя лучше, конечно, проверять регулярным выражением, их готовых полно на все случаи жизни.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
def check_int(s):
    if s[0] in ('-', '+'):
        return s[1:].isdigit()
    return s.isdigit()

check_int('-42')      # True
check_int('+42')      # True
check_int('42')       # True
```